# String comparison between Two Pyspark Dataframe but in many to many relationship

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

**df1**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My name is tom patil |
| 2 | My name yash patil |
| 3 | neha patil |

**df2**

| str_id | String |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | patil |
| 2 | yash |
| 3 | tom |
| 4 | yash patil |

**Expected Output**

| from_id | to_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |

df1 should be with df2 string column and then the mapping should take place

The logic I have used

```
In Pandas 

df1["name_temp"] = df1["Name"].astype(str).str.replace(r"\W+", " ", regex=True).str.strip().str.lower()
df2["string_temp"] = df2["String"].astype(str).str.replace(r"\W+", " ", regex=True).str.strip().str.lower()

new1 = df1["name_temp"].str.split(" ", expand = True)
new2 = df2["string_temp"].str.split(" ", expand = True)

df1 = df1.join(new1)
df2 = df2.join(new2)

df2_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df3_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df4_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df5_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df6_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df7_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df8_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df9_pandas = pd.DataFrame()
df10_pandas = pd.DataFrame()


df2_pandas["id2_1"] = df2["id"].copy()
df3_pandas["id3_1"] = df2["id"].copy()
df4_pandas["id4_1"] = df2["id"].copy()
df5_pandas["id5_1"] = df2['id'].copy()
df6_pandas["id6_1"] = df2["id"].copy()

df2_pandas["string2_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df3_pandas["string3_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df4_pandas["string4_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df5_pandas["string5_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df6_pandas["string6_1"] = df2[0].copy()

df2_pandas["string2_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df3_pandas["string3_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df4_pandas["string4_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df5_pandas["string5_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df6_pandas["string6_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df7_pandas["id7_1"] = df2["id"].copy()
df8_pandas["id8_1"] = df2["id"].copy()
df9_pandas["id9_1"] = df2["id"].copy()
df10_pandas["id10_1"] = df2["id"].copy()

df7_pandas["string7_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df8_pandas["string8_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df9_pandas["string9_1"] = df2[0].copy()
df10_pandas["string10_1"] = df2[0].copy()

df7_pandas["string7_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df8_pandas["string8_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df9_pandas["string9_2"] = df2[1].copy()
df10_pandas["string10_2"] = df2[1].copy()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled","true")
df1=spark.createDataFrame(df1)
df2=spark.createDataFrame(df2)
df2_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df2_pandas)
df3_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df3_pandas)
df4_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df4_pandas)
df5_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df5_pandas)
df6_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df6_pandas)
df7_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df7_pandas)
df8_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df8_pandas)
df9_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df9_pandas)
df10_pandas=spark.createDataFrame(df10_pandas)

df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("0","name_temp0")
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("1","name_temp1")
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("2","name_temp2")
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("3","name_temp3")
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("4","name_temp4")

df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("0","string_temp0")
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed("1","string_temp1")

df1 = df1.join(df2,(df1.name_temp0 == df2.string_temp0) & (df1.name_temp1 == df2.string_temp1) ,how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df2_pandas,(df1.name_temp1 == df2_pandas.string2_1) & (df1.name_temp2 == df2_pandas.string2_2) ,how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df3_pandas,(df1.name_temp2 == df3_pandas.string3_1) & (df1.name_temp3 == df3_pandas.string3_2) ,how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df4_pandas,(df1.name_temp3 == df4_pandas.string4_1) & (df1.name_temp4 == df4_pandas.string4_2) ,how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df5_pandas,(df1.name_temp4 == df5_pandas.string5_1) ,how='left')

from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df6_pandas = df6_pandas.filter("string6_2 IS  NULL")
df7_pandas = df7_pandas.filter("string7_2 IS  NULL")
df8_pandas = df8_pandas.filter("string8_2 IS  NULL")
df9_pandas = df9_pandas.filter("string9_2 IS  NULL")

df1 = df1.join(df6_pandas,(df1.name_temp0 == df6_pandas.string6_1),how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df7_pandas,(df1.name_temp1 == df7_pandas.string7_1),how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df8_pandas,(df1.name_temp2 == df8_pandas.string8_1),how='left')
df1 = df1.join(df9_pandas,(df1.name_temp3 == df9_pandas.string9_1),how='left')

from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, concat_ws
df1=df1.withColumn('id_all', concat_ws(",",df1.id,df1.id2_1,df1.id3_1,
df1.id4_1,
df1.id5_1,
df1.id6_1,
df1.id7_1,
df1.id8_1,
df1.id9_1))

display(df1)
```

| Name | id_all |
| --- | --- |
| neha patil | 1 |
| My name yash patil | 4,2,1 |
| My name is tom patil | 1,3 |

I want to optimize as well as the output is getting wrong.
Please help me with some other code.

Answer (score 0):

This will fails when the strings have more substring hierarchy. Until now, this will work only for the example above.

To compare the string with string, I have used the `contains` method. `df3` is the filtered dataframe that is the collection of strings where it is super string of the others.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = spark.read.csv('test1.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True, sep='\t')
df1.show(truncate=False)

+---+--------------------+
|id |Name                |
+---+--------------------+
|1  |My name is tom patil|
|2  |My name yash patil  |
|3  |neha patil          |
+---+--------------------+

df2 = spark.read.csv('test2.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True, sep='\t')
df2.show(truncate=False)

+------+----------+
|str_id|String    |
+------+----------+
|1     |patil     |
|2     |yash      |
|3     |tom       |
|4     |yash patil|
+------+----------+

df3 = df2.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'), f.col('b.String').contains(f.col('a.String')) & (f.col('a.String') != f.col('b.String')), 'leftanti')
df3.show(truncate=False)

+------+----------+
|str_id|String    |
+------+----------+
|3     |tom       |
|4     |yash patil|
+------+----------+

df = df1.join(df3, f.col('Name').contains(f.col('String')), 'left') \
  .withColumnRenamed('str_id', 'to_id').drop('String') \
  .join(df2, f.col('Name').contains(f.col('String')), 'left') \
  .withColumn('to_id', f.coalesce('to_id', 'str_id')) \
  .groupBy('id').agg(f.collect_set('to_id').alias('to_id')) \
  .withColumnRenamed('id', 'from_id') \
  .withColumn('to_id', f.concat_ws(',', f.array_sort('to_id')))
df.show(truncate=False)

+-------+-----+
|from_id|to_id|
+-------+-----+
|1      |1,3  |
|3      |1    |
|2      |4    |
+-------+-----+
```

Comment: But the expected output is not matching can I get some different logic as already their is a string yash patil completely then why to get substring again match???Please help me with it